# How to give cursor styling to textbox inside div which inturn have pointer-event as none

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox, which should not be clicked by the user, its value will be auto filled and should be passed to php then. So I went with this option.

```
   <div style="pointer-events: none;"> 
   <input id="dob" type='text' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" readonly style="background: white;**cursor: not-allowed !important;**"/>
</div>
```

but `cursor: not-allowed` is not affecting in the page.
Any help please?
Or other method to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, have you tried using `user-select: none;` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn it around:

```
 <div style="cursor: not-allowed; display: inline-block;"> 
     <input id="dob" type='text' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" readonly style="background: white; pointer-events: none;"/>
 </div>
```

The wrapper now has the cursor and your input does not have any pointer events. Note that `pointer-events` is not supported up top IE 10.

Comment: Thats great, but its changing the style of button layout, its actually a bootstrap button with calender icon attached in span.

Comment: Is it not with your solution? remove the `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I was just trying different display options, display:inherit worked. No alignment changes now

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="dob" type='text' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" readonly style="  cursor: none;"/>
```

try `cursor:none` property. the cursor is not visible on textbox.